# Error on Loading Data from a Reducer, Issue in await

Tags: react-native, redux, use-effect

I have an Issue when getting data from a Reducer.

The Issue I believe it is with the Async Code of the Data.

Here is my Code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Alert, ActivityIndicator, Button } from "react-native";
import { HeaderButtons, Item } from 'react-navigation-header-buttons';

import Colors from '../constants/Colors';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import * as boletoActions from '../store/actions/boletos';
import HeaderButton from '../components/UI/HeaderButton';

const Boleto = (props) => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState(false);
    const [isRefreshing, setIsRefreshing] = useState(false);

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const userId = useSelector(state => state.auth.userId);
    const gameId = useSelector(state => state.boleto.currentGameId);

    const loadBoleto = useCallback(async (userId, gameId) => {
        setError(null);
        setIsRefreshing(true);
        try {
            await dispatch(boletoActions.getTicket(userId, gameId));
        } catch (err) {
            setError(err.message);
        }
        setIsRefreshing(false);
    }, [dispatch, setLoading, setError]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribeGuardados = props.navigation.addListener('focus', loadBoleto);

        return () => {
            unsubscribeGuardados();
        };
    }, [loadBoleto]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(true);
        loadBoleto(userId, gameId).then(() => {
            setLoading(false);
        });
    }, [dispatch, loadBoleto]);

    const boletoInfo = useSelector(state => state.boleto.ticket);

    var codigo = boletoInfo.length != 0 ? boletoInfo[0].id : '';
    var cantidad = boletoInfo.length != 0 ? boletoInfo[0].cantidad : ''; 
    var localidad = boletoInfo.length != 0 ? boletoInfo[0].nombreLocalidad : '';
    var local = boletoInfo.length != 0 ? boletoInfo[0].local : '';
    var visitante = boletoInfo.length != 0 ? boletoInfo[0].visita : '';
    var logo = boletoInfo.length != 0 ? boletoInfo[0].logo : '';
    var usado = boletoInfo.length != 0 ? boletoInfo[0].usado : '';
    
    if (loading) {
        return <View style={styles.centered} >
            <ActivityIndicator size='large' color={Colors.primary} />
        </View>
    }

    if (!error === null) {
        return <View style={styles.centered} >
            <Text style={styles.errorText}>No se pudo Cargar el Ticket</Text>
            <Button title='Recargar' onPress={loadBoleto} color={Colors.secondary} />
        </View>
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.centered}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>Codigo Transaccion: <Text style={styles.title2}>{codigo}</Text></Text>
            <Text style={styles.title}>Cantidad: <Text style={styles.title2}>{cantidad}</Text></Text>
            <Text style={styles.title}>Localidad: <Text style={styles.title2}>{localidad}</Text></Text>
            <Text style={styles.title}>Local: <Text style={styles.title2}>{local}</Text></Text>
            <Text style={styles.title}>Visitante: <Text style={styles.title2}>{visitante}</Text></Text>
            <Text style={styles.title}>logo: <Text style={styles.title2}>{logo}</Text></Text>
        </View>
    );
};

export const screenOptions = navData => {
    return {
        headerTitle: 'Boleto',
        headerLeft: () => (<HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
            <Item
                title='Back'
                iconName={Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'md-arrow-back-outline' : 'ios-arrow-back-outline'}
                onPress={() => {
                    navData.navigation.navigate('Noticias');
                }} />
        </HeaderButtons>)
    }
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    centered: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    title: {
        marginTop: 15,
        marginBottom: 5,
        fontSize: 20,
        color: 'black',
        alignContent: 'center',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
    title2: {
        marginTop: 15,
        marginBottom: 5,
        fontSize: 20,
        color: Colors.primary,
        alignContent: 'center',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
    errorText: {
        marginTop: 15,
        marginBottom: 5,
        fontSize: 20,
        color: Colors.secondary,
        alignContent: 'center',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
});

export default Boleto;
```

Now the first time I access I see this:

[image: Image Empty]

I think this is because on loading it ***boletoInfo*** is Length less than 0, however if I add a console.log to this Page, it shows the info.

[image: Added Console Log X]

I added in that picture the line `console.log('x');`

And then I see this:

[image: Info Loaded]

I need to display the info as soon as I Load the page.

Any Ideas?

Comment: You could show a loading spinner if it's not ready, but you can't show data that doesn't exist yet.  I would make sure that the ticket exists before attempting to render it rather than using empty strings.

Comment: Sorry in the code how would you add that as to me  loadBoleto those that but not sure as loadBoleto calls on to the reducer any thing I could do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to make sure that the ticket exists before you attempt to render it.  Is it possible that all of the actions complete, but the user doesn't have a ticket to this game?

Instead of falling back to empty strings, you should avoid that section entirely if there is not ticket.  I'm moving that code block to a separate component that we can call.

```
// only render this component when you know that you have a ticket
export const RenderBoleto = ({boleto}) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.centered}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>
        Codigo Transaccion: <Text style={styles.title2}>{boleto.id}</Text>
      </Text>
      <Text style={styles.title}>
        Cantidad: <Text style={styles.title2}>{boleto.cantidad}</Text>
      </Text>
      <Text style={styles.title}>
        Localidad: <Text style={styles.title2}>{boleto.nombreLocalidad}</Text>
      </Text>
      <Text style={styles.title}>
        Local: <Text style={styles.title2}>{boleto.local}</Text>
      </Text>
      <Text style={styles.title}>
        Visitante: <Text style={styles.title2}>{boleto.visita}</Text>
      </Text>
      <Text style={styles.title}>
        logo: <Text style={styles.title2}>{boleto.logo}</Text>
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

---

You have defined the callback `loadBoleto` as a function that takes arguments `userId` and `gameId`.  But there are some places where you are calling it that don't make sense.  When it's called through the `onPress` of a `Button` or a listener of `props.navigation` then the argument will be the event -- not the `userId` and `gameId`.

You could change your current function or create a wrapper function that calls it.  This function takes no arguments because it uses the `userId` and `gameId` from the selectors.  But it needs to have them as dependencies.

```
// defines a callback that loads a ticket for THIS CURRENT userId and gameId
const loadCurrentBoleto = useCallback(
  async () => {
    loadBoleto(userId, gameId);
  },
  [loadBoleto, userId, gameId]
)
```

---

We can create a variable for the first element of the `boletoInfo` `array`.  If this `boleto` variable doesn't exist then we should show the error screen, even if the action completed without an error.  I'm setting the initial value of `loading` to `true` just to make sure that the very first thing we see is loading screen.

```
const Boleto = (props) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const userId = useSelector((state) => state.auth.userId);
  const gameId = useSelector((state) => state.boleto.currentGameId);

  // returns an array
  const boletoInfo = useSelector((state) => state.boleto.ticket);

  // is either a ticket object or undefined depending on the length of the array
  const boleto = boletoInfo[0];

  // defines a callback that loads a ticket for THIS CURRENT userId and gameId
  const loadCurrentBoleto = useCallback(
    async () => {
      setError(null);
      setLoading(true);
      try {
        await dispatch(boletoActions.getTicket(userId, gameId));
      } catch (err) {
        setError(err.message);
      }
      setLoading(false);
    },
    [dispatch, setLoading, setError, userId, gameId]
  )

  // need to use loadCurrentBoleto here instead of loadBoleto
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribeGuardados = props.navigation.addListener(
      "focus",
      loadCurrentBoleto
    );

    return () => {
      unsubscribeGuardados();
    };
  }, [loadCurrentBoleto]);


   // load ticket automatically
  useEffect(() => {
     // can we skip this is boleto is defined?
      loadCurrentBoleto();
  }, [dispatch, loadCurrentBoleto]);

  if (loading) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.centered}>
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color={Colors.primary} />
      </View>
    );
  }

  if (boleto) {
    return (
      <RenderBoleto boleto={boleto}/>
    )
  }

  // show error screen if boleto undefined
  return (
    <View style={styles.centered}>
      <Text style={styles.errorText}>No se pudo Cargar el Ticket</Text>
      <Button
        title="Recargar"
        onPress={loadCurrentBoleto}
        color={Colors.secondary}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: You are the Best, Thank you.